# What does "local solution" mean in svm?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I have read about svm. I just confused between "global solution" and "local solution".

Can anyone help me about the difference between them?

Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to add some more detail to your question before anyone knows what you're talking about.

Comment: I am talking generally. I just want to know what the local solution means.

Answer (score 1):

In general "local solution" vs. "global solution" means "best in some fixed surrounding" and "best in the whole set of possible values" respectively. So for example if you analyze the [cos(10x)/x](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%2810x%29/x) function in order to find the minimum value for positive x, you will find it around "x~0.28" (global solution) although there are many local minima ie. `x~0.93` ( http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min%5B+cos%2810x%29%2Fx%2C+x%3E0+%5D )

This concept is of crucial importance in machine learning (and so in SVM) as many learning models do not have efficient methods of finding global solution for their problems (which leads to worse learning effects). One of the reasons behind SVM success is the fact that it has a guarantee (assuming enough time and perfect numerical precision) to converge to the global optimum, and so - finding best possible set of parameters in the largest margin sense.

Comment: Thanks, I've been reading a tutorial about SVM, and I found this sentence "every local solution is global solution" as a property of convex programming problem ,, What does that mean??

Comment: This mean, that in the convex optimization (which SVM is a particular example) there is just **one** solution. So there is no local-global distinction - once you find a "local" minimum you have guarantee that it is in fact the **global** one. Think about simplest case - quadratic function (like f(x)=x^2+ax+c) it has just one minimum, and it is convex. But some functions, which are not convex have multiple minima - like the one in my answer